# polymer does not bind from outside

Tags: polymer

`my-form` does not `iLoadChanged`

```
    <my-form iDB="{{iDB}}" iLoad="{{iLoad}}"></my-form>
    <catalog-1 iDB="{{iDB}}"></catalog-1>
    <my-database iDB="{{iDB}}" iLoad="{{iLoad}}"></my-database>
```

But it does work when I put `my-database` inside `my-form`?

my-form

```
<polymer-element name="my-form" attributes="iDB iLoad">
    <template>
        ...
        <my-database iDB="{{iDB}}" iLoad="{{iLoad}}"></my-database>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('my-form', {
            iLoad:false,
            iDB:null,

            iLoadChanged:function(){
                console.log('Hello?') 
            },
```

my-database

```
<polymer-element name="my-database" attributes="iDB iLoad iDrop">
    <script>
        Polymer('my-database', {
            iDB:null,
            iLoad:false,
            ready:function(){
                var load=function(){
                    this.iLoad=true
                    console.log('iLoad',this.iLoad)
                }.bind(this)
                var request = indexedDB.open("my-database",1);
                request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
                    var db = e.currentTarget.result
                    var store = db.createObjectStore("store", {keyPath: "muts", autoIncrement:false})
                    //store.createIndex("by_submit", "submit", {unique: false})
                    console.log('db upgrade', 'v'+db.version)
                }
                request.onerror = function(e) {
                    //var db = e.currentTarget.result;
                    //db.close()
                    console.error('db error ',e)
                }
                request.onsuccess = function(e) {
                    var db = e.currentTarget.result
                    db.onversionchange = function(e) {
                        db.close()
                        console.log('db changed', 'v'+db.version, 'CLOSED')
                    }
                    console.log('db setup', 'v'+db.version, 'OK')
                    load()
                }
                this.iDB=request
            },
            iDrop: function () {
                this.iDB.result.close()
                var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(this.iDB.result.name);
                req.onsuccess = function() {console.log("Deleted database successfully")}
                req.onerror = function() {console.log("Couldn't delete database")}
                req.onblocked = function() {console.log("Couldn't delete database due to the operation being blocked")}
            }
        })
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

How can I make it work from outside `my-form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use a polymer wrapper.

```
<polymer-element name="my-wrapper">
    <my-form drawer iDB="{{iDB}}" iLoad="{{iLoad}}"></my-form>
    <catalog-1 main iDB="{{iDB}}" page="{{page}}" muts="{{muts}}"></catalog-1>
    <my-database iDB="{{iDB}}" iLoad="{{iLoad}}"></my-database>
    ...
```

Comment: Have you seen `<template is="auto-binding">`? https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding

Comment: yes but did not understand it at the time haha :) going to read it again :) PS your website should mention "use element 30s, create element 5m, build app 30m and understanding what you are doing 5 years :P